# How to combine ppm image files in C using only system calls?

Tags: c, image-processing, system-calls, ppm, unistd.h

I've found some similar questions on the internet, but not with system calls.

I'm doing an exercise in my system programming class. It asks you to combine ppm image files in binary form(`P6`, not `P3`) using only system calls. Input is taken from command line. The first input is the larger image file, the second input is the smaller image file, and after the inputs the files are combined and written into a third file, which you can specify the name of as a third input. The smaller file is written into the top-right of the larger file.

Since we're using system calls, I'm assuming we're mainly using `open/read/write/lseek`. I know that my ppm files will store the magic number `P6` at the beginning, and then the width and height of the file. I know that I can use `lseek` by writing from the left side of row 1 of the larger ppm file, then stopping when my pointer reaches the difference in size between the two files, and writing the remaining pixels for the line from the smaller file. Then continuing, line by line...

However, I have no idea how to implement this. I'm not sure how to even read the width and height of the file, either. I'm sort of lost. *Can someone help me get on the right track?* I'd post my code if I actually had anything meaningful, but I just created file descriptors for the files and opened them so far.

EDIT:

I combine them by overwriting the top right of the larger file with the smaller file. I'm not guaranteed anything about the images, so I have to somehow pull the width and height from both files and compare them, to make sure the first file has both a larger width and height than the second.

I think they want us to loop through the files, pixel by pixel, reading each rgb group of values for each pixel using `read`. Then writing in a loop, pixel by pixel, using `write`.

EDIT2:

Here's a list of unix system calls. They're available in the c library, but this is all I'm allowed to use: http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html

Comment: How do you "combine" them? Are they supposed to be concatenated together? Are you guaranteed anything about the images having the same width or height?

Comment: *It asks you to combine ppm image files in binary form(P6, not P3) using only system calls.* System calls?  So, you have to do something like write platform-specific assembler code to issue kernel traps directly?

Comment: @J.J I think what Andrew was pointing out is that you're using the incorrect term. C standard functions are not "system calls". Also, your description of exactly what you're supposed to do is pertinent to answering your question, so you should [edit] it with your comments included, and then delete your comments.

Comment: Sorry if I'm incorrect, my prof defines it as a system call so I'm not sure! :P http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/read.htm Now I'm more confused.

Comment: Ah, if you're supposed to use `<unistd.h>`, then your professor is correct. I misunderstood.

Comment: Okay, I put my comments in the question. And it's okay, I might not be clear at explaining, sorry. :(

Comment: I'm not sure when you need to do this by, but I'll be able to answer tonight if no one else answers before then. In the meanwhile, break your project down into smaller goals, such as figuring out how to overwrite one pixel (say, the top right of the larger image) with some arbitrary color, then figure out how to overwrite it with a color from the top right of the smaller image, and so on.

Comment: **General advice**: Be aware that PPM files can be 8-bit or 16-bit depending on whether the number after the width is 255 or 65535. Make test images of different colours so you can easily tell them apart in the debugger - maybe use **ImageMagick**. E.g. red-blue gradient of 800x600, `magick -size 800x600 gradient:red-blue -depth 8 RedBlue.ppm` or a solid yellow image `magick -size 200x100 xc:yellow -depth 8 yellow.ppm`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Indeed.  I really wonder where the distinction between "system calls" and "functions" comes from.  C code calls *functions*.  Full stop.  Even [the Linux `syscall()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) is a *function* and the documentation says as much: "syscall() is a small **library function** ..."

Comment: Most often PPM uses an 8-bit depth, so I think that's a safe assumption, and possibly something that can be confirmed by emailing the professor. I've never even heard of a monitor that supports displaying 16-bit depth images.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not all images (PPM and otherwise) are necessarily for displaying on a monitor - some are high resolution/range results of experiments and are stored as 64-bit floats for example.

Comment: Good point, but I'm still confident my suggestion applies in this situation, given the frequent use of the word "image", and the nature of the assignment, blitting the files together.

Comment: @ Downvote/closevote: Please note this is someone's first question on Stack Overflow, and consider giving some feedback to improve the question if you feel it is too broad (which in my opinion, it is not).

Comment: @MarkSetchell My images show the number after the width is 255 for both inputs, so I'm assuming it's 8-bit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Here's a list of the system calls: http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html